# Formatting different types of data in CSV columns using Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing multiple dictionaries to a csv file using Python. The first column is an column with IDS, the next several are float data formatted to a precision of two decimal places, and the last is string data. I'm a beginner, so this error message is throwing me for a loop.

```
print TotalData
({0.0: 7194.9500000000035, 1.0: 2456.1200000000003, 2.0: 2333.0699999999997, 3.0: 1645.37}, {0.0: 27400.0, 1.0: 32900.0, 2.0: 42200.0, 3.0: 40600.0}, {0.0: 33, 1.0: 35, 2.0: 35, 3.0: 42}, {0.0: 1800.0, 1.0: 1900.0, 2.0: 1900.0, 3.0: 1800.0}, {0.0: 800.0, 1.0: 500.0, 2.0: 400.0, 3.0: 500.0}, {0.0: 830.30303030303025, 1.0: 940.0, 2.0: 1205.7142857142858, 3.0: 966.66666666666663}, {0.0: 101.48148148148148, 1.0: 82.25, 2.0: 136.1290322580645, 3.0: 101.49999999999999}, {0.0: -400.0, 1.0: 7100.0, 2.0: -11200.0, 3.0: -600.0}, {0.0: -0.014598540145985401, 1.0: 0.21580547112462006, 2.0: -0.26540284360189575, 3.0: -0.014778325123152709}, {0.0: 'POINT(254123,8.03835e+06)', 1.0: 'POINT(254603,8.03829e+06)', 2.0: 'POINT(254905,8.03863e+06)', 3.0: 'POINT(254606,8.03871e+06)'})
```

Those are my dictionaries.

```
TotalData = LongCanal, ConsoSom, ConsoCompte,  ConsoMax, ConsoMin, ConsoMoyn, Rendement, vFuites, ILP, XYcoord
ListData = list(TotalData)

with open('AEP_data.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(['FID_CG', 'LongCanal', 'ConsoSom', 'ConsoCompte', 'ConsoMax', 'ConsoMin', 'ConsoMoyn', 'Rendement', 'vFuites', 'ILP', 'XYcoord'])
    for key in sorted(LongCanal.iterkeys(), key=lambda x: int(x)):
        writer.writerow([key] + ['{0:.2f}'.format(d[key]) for d in TotalData[0:8]] + [d[key] for d in TotalData[9]])



TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

When I remove the string dictionary, and format all float values to '{0:.2f}' everything works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Mahalo in advance.

Comment: Do you still have a question/problem? If so, please ask away. If not, you should accept an answer or post your own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that one of the things you THINK is a dictionary, is actually just a float. If we try to print the last part of your `writer` statement:

```
print [d[key] for d in TotalData[9]]
```

We get this same error as above:

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So we have identified the source of the problem.

I can not quite tell what you are trying to do, but your `key` parameter exactly matches the values of `d` in this last list comprehension. Because of that, I am going to go ahead and guess this is what you want:

```
for key in sorted(LongCanal.iterkeys(), key=lambda x: int(x)):
    writer.writerow([key] + ['{0:.2f}'.format(d[key]) for d in TotalData[0:8]] + [TotalData[9][key]])
```

Comment: I have several dictionaries that correspond with columns in a csv file. All keys of the dictionaries are the same, as they fall under a first ID column. Now, most of my data should be formatted with 2 decimal precision, but the last column is string data so it isn't. I'm still not sure why TotalData[9] is considered a 'float' object.

Comment: The 'float' value in question is because you were the `d[key]` values were: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0.  The KEYS were float, not the actual values; which, you are totally right, were strings.